# Log files keep growing fast on Debian testing (bullseye)

Tags: linux, debian, log-files

I've just reinstalled my system (Debian testing, bullseye). But I found a problem that I've never met before. Three log files in `/var/log` keep growing fast: `/var/log/messages`, `/var/log/user.log` and `/var/log/syslog`. The content in these 3 files are almost **exactly the same**. They seems produced by my proxy tool [`Shadowsocks.AppImage`](https://github.com/shadowsocks/shadowsocks-qt5) (The `Shadowsocks.desktop` works well, I don't know why it says "TCP connection timeout"):

```sh
Jul 20 21:07:32 localhost Shadowsocks.desktop[1065]: TCP connection timeout.
Jul 20 21:07:32 localhost Shadowsocks.desktop[1065]: TCP connection timeout.
Jul 20 21:07:32 localhost Shadowsocks.desktop[1065]: TCP connection timeout.
Jul 20 21:07:32 localhost Shadowsocks.desktop[1065]: TCP connection timeout.
Jul 20 21:07:32 localhost Shadowsocks.desktop[1065]: TCP connection timeout.
Jul 20 21:07:32 localhost Shadowsocks.desktop[1065]: TCP connection timeout.
Jul 20 21:07:32 localhost Shadowsocks.desktop[1065]: TCP connection timeout.
Jul 20 21:07:32 localhost Shadowsocks.desktop[1065]: TCP connection timeout.
Jul 20 21:07:32 localhost Shadowsocks.desktop[1065]: TCP connection timeout.
Jul 20 21:07:32 localhost Shadowsocks.desktop[1065]: TCP connection timeout.
```

Currently I wrote a script to empty these files every 30 minutes. But this cannot solve the problem. Every file could be more than 300MB in 30 minutes, which may damage the SSD drive since it brings a lot of useless Read/Write operations.

Any one know how to solve it? Thanks a lot!

The desktop entry for AppImage:

```sh
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Shadowsocks
Exec=/home/username/Tools/Shadowsocks-Qt5-3.0.1-x86_64.AppImage
Icon=/home/username/Tools/shadowsocks-256.png
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Categories=Office;
MimeType=text/plain
```

Comment: How do you know that Shadowsocks works well? If you disable/uninstall it, does the problem persist?

Comment: Thank you. (1) I think it works well because I can connect the internet through shadowsocks's proxy and I have being using the same configuration on Ubuntu and Debian(buster) for a long time.The problem arose since I upgraded my system from Debian buster to Debian bullseye.      (2) If I close the proxy, the log files do not grow so fast, but completely same contents are still written into `messages`, `syslog` and `user.log`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be dependency-related issue with Shadowsocks-Qt5.

Per the author,

> I don't think the logs were from this application. Could it be from Qt? Are you using the official Qt rpms or your own compiled version?

**Resources**

- https://github.com/shadowsocks/shadowsocks-qt5/issues/728

Comment: Thank you! I've reinstalled qt5 library but it didn't help. Then I decided not to use shadowsocks-qt5 and chose another version. The frequent error messages  didn't appear.